# Warnings in QML: Delegate in separate file and access on model item properties

Tags: qt, qml

The following code works and shows my items correctly, but I get the warning

```
qrc:/TableDelegate.qml:24: ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

I think it is because the ListView tries to access the model when it is empty and can not reference the item properties. I assume I am not doing to it correctly but I do not know how to do it better.

So my question is: how to get rid of the warning by doing it the right way?

TableDelegate.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Item {
    property color bgcolor: 'transparent'
    property alias box: rowBox

    height: 40
    width: parent.width
    Rectangle {
        id: rowBox
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: bgcolor
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Rectangle {
                id: tableNameColumn
                color: 'transparent'
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    color: textcolor
                    text: name                // <--- here is `name`
                }
            }
            // More Columns ...
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
             view.currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like this

TableView.qml:

```
// ...

ListModel {
    id: model
}

ListView {
    id: view
    model: model
    anchors.fill: parent
    highlight: delegate_highlighted
    highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
    delegate: delegate
}

Component {
    id: delegate
    TableDelegate {
        bgcolor: 'transparent';
    }
}

Component {
    id: delegate_highlighted
    TableDelegate {
        bgcolor: 'lightsteelblue'
        box.border.color: 'black'
        box.radius: 3
    }
}

// ...
```

Comment: The simplest would be, to check whether the value is defined or not like this:

    `text: (model.name !== undefined ? model.name : '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a `TableDelegate` for the highlight. That is wrong.

The ListView creates 1 instance of the highlight item, that will be drawn as a background for the currently selected item, It may also move between items as transition when the current item changes. It should only be a rectangle or whatever you want to use.

In your example, the highlight item is a full delegate, that wants to access model data, which it cannot.

Comment: Indeed that was it! Thank you so much! I really misunderstood the highlight property!